# Total variation distance between multinomial laws

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Can someone help me with the following problem:

Let $P_n$ and $Q_n$ two multinomial laws with parameters $(p,n)$ and $(q,n)$, where $p$ and $q$ are two probability measures on some measurable space and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that $\|P_n-Q_n\|_{TV}$ is non decreasing in $n$? I think that it is, but I cannot prove it...

Thank you.

Alainty

Comment: @SergueiPopov, Alainty it seems I did misunderstand the question so i deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assume both measures put positive probability on all outcomes.  The total variation distance can be written $E_Q|1-\frac {dP_n}{dQ_n}|$.  The likelihood ratio is a martingale, so the integrand is a submartingale and so it's expectation is increasing.

Comment: Ok, right! Thank you very much michael!!

Comment: This is essentially correct, but there might be some confusion between the product measures $p^n$ and $q^n$, and the multinomial measures that are their projections. The reason the proof works is that a symmetry argument shows that the total variation distance is not changed by the projection. Working directly with the multinomial measures would require a proof of the Martingale property since the corresponding $\sigma$ fields are not increasing.